# I'm trying to understand depth first search. Don't know if I'm correct

Tags: graph, traversal, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEJKz.png

The image shows a graph. Is this a correct depth first traversal? Or have I got the idea completely wrong? My understanding of dfs is given a starting point, you look at all the adjacent nodes. Then, arbitrarily pick one and 'visit' that node recursively. Starting from v, I've picked node 2 to go to next. The numbers from 1 - 8 show the path.

Edit: I seem to have mixed the numbers 2 and 3 up! They should be swapped.

Image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdWl6.png

Answer (score 0):

What you show is a correct possible DFS search order.  DFS visits recursively as you've said, marking nodes it has already visited.  When it reaches a point where it cannot recurse to an unvisited node, it will backtrack until there is a such a point or the search terminates because all nodes are marked as visited.

In your case, it visits 1, 2, and 3.  At 3, it backtracks to 2, then continues to 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.  It would then backtrack, but all nodes are visited so the search terminates with this visiting order.

The node marked 3 in this case, could also have been 2 or 8.  For example, DFS could have gone (using the labels from your figure): 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, backtrack to 2, 3, terminate.

Comment: So without changing anything in the picture, going from 1 to 3 and then 2 and then to the rest of the nodes would result in a path 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 with no backtracking?

All edges don't need to be visited and this is a correct dfs path, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  An implementation may or may not backtrack to the start before terminating, depending on how it tracks visited nodes, but conceptually it doesn't need to backtrack in that case since all nodes are visited once it reaches 8.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, how would the path differ for bfs and why?

Comment: I've added another image to the question description. The numbers are in the right place now. Am I right in saying that the traversal shown is the same for bfs and dfs?